# Spring cloud data flow unable to find file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created a microservice in springboot, there is folder under resource folder and then a file under this folder
i,e.

```
resource
      mycustomfolder
                  myfile.txt
```

I am creating a bean, which filed populated by `myfile`

```
@Value("${file-path}")
    private String filePath;

 @Bean
    public MyBean byBean() throws IOException {
//read file path
        String path = ResourceUtils.getURL(filePath).getPath();
//populated by bean
        MyBean myBean = myservice.populatedMyBean(path);
        return myBean;
    }
```

filePath value is set in application.property

```
dataload-config-file=src/main/resources/mycustomfolder/myfile.txt
```

when i am executing this springboot app it's working file.

But when i am creating a jar of it and deploying with spring cloud data flow it giving me error on creating myBean
showing exception cause

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spring-cloud-dataflow-4865534318197521357/test-1506882530191/test.process/src/main/resources/mycustomfolder/myfile.txt (No such file or directory)
```

why this is happning normally working fine, but throwing error with spring-cloud-dataflow?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Data Flow can *only* orchestrate Spring Cloud Stream (SCSt) or Spring Cloud Task (SCT) based microservice applications. It is unclear whether your Spring Boot application complies to previously mentioned frameworks.

Please use the [SCSt](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) and [SCT](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples) samples for reference. If your application does comply with the SCSt/SCT programming model, it'd be better you share the source code for review.